# cPanel multiple domains and SSLs under a single account

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel

I have to set a multiple domains under a single cPanel because the they both need to point to the same document root.

I have successfully added the secondary domain under Domains, and I was able able to upload another SSL certificate for this domain.

However, looks like I am only be able to install one SSL certificate at a time, when I tried to install the secondary SSL, the first one automatically stopped working.

How I can configure cPanel to have both SSLs working? or in this case, do I have to use a single SSL that supports multiple domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you add each domain as "Addon" under your cPanel, your hosting provider's free SSL- either, Let's Encrypt or cPanel's SSLs should be able to cover EACH addon domain with a different SSL Certificate and they should not interfere with each other.
If you still experience issues with that, I would recommend reaching your hosting provider to check that further for you and let you know how this can be achieved in their environment.

If they lack support, then I would recommend checking out for a managed hosting provider which will take care of this configuration for you.